# Try::Tiny is not working with exit statment in perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I was trying to use [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) package from cpan, and have written simple code as below

```
use strict;
use Try::Tiny;
print "before try block";
try {
        print "try block";
        my $test = 10/0;
} catch {
        print "got error :- $_ \n";
}
exit;
```

when i execute this it shows no error and
gives o/p like "before try block" and ends without printing "try block" statement.

but when i comment

```
#exit;
```

i works fine and shows print statement in catch block,am i doing something wrong?
just trying to find what went wrong.

Comment: There is almost never any reason to call [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html "perldoc -f exit") directly.

Comment: @Brad I was implementing try,catch on script so instead commenting remaining code i used exit.

Comment: You shouldn't have fixed the problem in your question. It now doesn't exhibit the problem you are asking about.

Comment: @Brad-edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need a `;` (semi-colon) in the end of the try-catch

```
} catch {
        print "got error :- $_ \n";
};
```

From their examples on [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm)

Besides, do you need `exit`??

(courtesy ysth)
**explanation:** catch takes two parameters: a code block, and an optional parameter intended to be the finally clause...but here it is being passed the return value of exit as the second parameter, which it would complain about except that exit never returns.

Comment: @Ganesh np, even their cpan does not explicitly specify, was just a guess.

Comment: explanation: catch takes two parameters: a code block, and an optional parameter intended to be the finally clause...but here it is being passed the return value of exit as the second parameter, which it would complain about except that exit never returns.

Comment: The missing semi-colon got me for a while, thanks for the solution.